# What is wrong with my logic and derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, soft-question

Since the derivative of a function is analogous to a description on how fast the function grows, I thought that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=0$ for the following reason.

Assume $f(x)$ is monotone increasing on an interval $(a,\infty]$.  If $f'(x)$ is large, that means that $f(x)$ is getting larger and larger.  From this, I've assumed that $f'(x)$ must eventually be outdone by $f(x)$ simply because $f'(x)$ cannot get large without making $f(x)$ even larger.

But that's obviously not the case because if $f(x)=\Gamma(x)$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\ne0$.

I'm just wondering what is wrong with my logic, that's all.

Comment: $e^x$ is an even simpler counterexample

Comment: Notice that $f'(x)/f(x)=(\log(f(x)))'$, so you are asking about the growth of the log of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short there exist functions such as $e^x$ whose derivative increases at a rate equal to the function itself. You make an incorrect assumption *precisely* here:

> "From this, I've assumed that $f′(x)$ must eventually be outdone by $f(x)$ simply because $f′(x)$ cannot get large without making $f(x)$ even larger."

With that being said, these sorts of questions are really quite laudable.

Answer (score 1):

Just because $f(x)$ is "getting larger and larger" doesn't mean that $f'(x)$ "must eventually be outdone by $f(x)$." For example: what if $f'(x)$ itself gets larger and larger, at the same or greater rate than $f(x)$, and starts out equal to or greater than $f(x)$? The comments and other answer give you simple counterexamples. The function $x\mapsto e^x$ has this property: its derivative starts out at the same value and grows at the same rate.

Moreover, I suspect your intuition about asymptotic growth at infinity is wrong: even *if* the claim above were true, it would not entail that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=0$.

In other words: just because $g(x)$ is eventually larger than $h(x)$ (that is, $g>h$ for all sufficiently large $x$) does not mean their ratio $h/g$ tends to 0 as $x$ tends to infinity. For example, the function $g(x)=2x$ is eventually greater than the function $h(x)=x$, but that does not mean $h/g=\frac{1}{2}$ tends to zero at infinity.